# Finding files in CVS repository

Tags: svn, repository, cvs

It is my first experience with CVS repository.

In repository are dozens of projects. The only way so I could recognize projects (project names are not helpful in identyfying) are some file names which I know from each project.

Example (structure that I see in Eclipse CVS repository view):

```
+Project1
+Project2
-Project3
  +Project3_1
  -Project3_2
    -Project3_2_1
      +.settings
      +src
      +WebContent
      -xml
        someuniquexml.xml
  +Project3_3
+Project4
```

In example, I know filename "someuniquexml.xml".

How could I as simple as possible find out, that "someuniquexml.xml" is in "Project3/Project3_2/Project3_2_1/xml"? For now I have to expand each project and find it manually...

Could I do that in Eclipse or do I need another tools?

Comment: If you want to use `Eclipse`, you can press CTRL+SHIFT+R to open `Open Resource` dialog. Type in the unique name and your file will appear. Then you can right click it and `Show In > Project Explorer` where you can see it's ancestors.

Comment: It works only for resources that are Checked out from repository. Instead of checking out all projects from repo, I would like to know a way to find proper project in repo, and then Check out it.